# How to figure out how to reference a dataSet in a C# portable class library?

Tags: c#, architecture, dataset, reusability

I have 3 different projects that use the same dataTables in the same dataSet.

I'm trying to create a portable library to cut down on the same code across the different projects.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to include a reference for the data-set?

Currently all 3 of my projects have their own data-set and I'm trying to simplify it.

I hope that I'm making sense.!

Please guide me with best possible way..

Comment: It means you want single data set and datable for use multiple project right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create N-Tier architecture will solve your problem

Your project architecture should be like this ,

```
Solution(your project) 
|
|-  Project 1
|
|-  Project 2
|
|-  Project 3
|
|-  DAL - //Data access layer 
|
|-  BL - //your business logic will be here
```

and just need reference where you want to use 
e.g.

```
yourproject.Dal.yourclass.yourmethod()
```

for more information just refer this  MVC project  [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En)

You can create same in your asp.net project

Answer (score 2):

First let me note, that Imran's advice is solid and you should definitely consider going this way; it is clear and offers a good path for growth. +1 for this!

But since you asked specifically about a 'portable DataSet' I translate that into 'Reusable DataSet' which imediatly points towards `OOP`. And since C# is OO all over, you can go right ahead and create a **custom DataSet**:

Below is a minimalistic example to encapsulate a few `Access` tables in a custom `DataSet`.
For other DBMSs change to the appropriate classes!

This simple class inherits from `DataSet` and uses the `Connectstring` as the only parameter in its constructor. I stores two user tables and for good measure the `usertables` schema.

Obviously you will want to expand this greatly..

```
public class myDataSet : DataSet
{

    OleDbConnection conn;
    OleDbDataAdapter DBDA;
    OleDbCommand SqlCmd;
    string ConnectionString = @"your default connection string here!";

    public myDataSet (string connectString)
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connectString)) 
                conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        else conn.ConnectionString = connectString;

        connectMe();

        DataTable userTables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");

        SqlCmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Names]", conn);
        DBDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
        DataTable Names = new DataTable("Names");
        DBDA.Fill(Names); 

        SqlCmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Places]", conn);
        DBDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
        DataTable Places= new DataTable("Places");
        DBDA.Fill(Places);

        conn.Close();

        this.Tables.Add(userTables);
        this.Tables.Add(Names);
        this.Tables.Add(Places);

    }

    public bool connectMe()
    {
        try { conn.Open();  } 
        catch { /* your error hanfdilng here! */}
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Since it is a regular class you can add Properties and Methods as you like; for re-retrieveing as well as Updating etc.. As usual class design is an art an will take some consideration as well as repeated refinements. Your current needs are a good starting point but planning for growth will pay.

Two more notes:

- Inheriting directly from DataSet is a simple way. Often it is better to create a class, that is `composited` from various other classes. So maybe you will end up with a Class *myDbStuff* with a *myDataSet* as one member.
- **Creating DB-Access objects** and going for **3-Tier architecture** are **not** mutally exclusive; in fact they go very well together; just make sure you know in time where the sparating lines will go..

To make the example work do this:

- Create a class library project with the neccessary refences and uses clauses and compile it.
- Then refer to the resulting DLL and the namespace of it in all your projects.